# Paired barplots keep overlapping, How can I separate them?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to have a paried barplot with before and after using ggplot, but they are just keep overlaping. Here is my code.

```
ggplot(fish, aes(x = Treat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = AvgAUPre, fill = "Before"),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
    width = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = AvgAUPost, fill = "After"),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge(width = -0.8),
    width = 0.4
  ) +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Area Use", fill = "Time") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("Before" = "lightblue", "After" = "orange")
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I tried adjusting thw position_dodge, width. But it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using multiple `geom_bar`s. to create a dodged bar chart. In that case `position_dodge` will not work. Instead you have to use `position_nudge` to shift the bars manually.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

fish <- data.frame(
  Treat = LETTERS[1:3],
  AvgAUPre = 1:3,
  AvgAUPost = 2:4
)

ggplot(fish, aes(x = Treat)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = AvgAUPre, fill = "Before"),
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.2),
    width = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_col(aes(y = AvgAUPost, fill = "After"),
    position = position_nudge(x = -0.2),
    width = 0.4
  ) +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Area Use", fill = "Time") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("Before" = "lightblue", "After" = "orange")
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

However, the recommended option would be to make your dataset tidy by reshaping it using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
fish |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(AvgAUPre, AvgAUPost), names_to = "Time") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Treat, y = value, fill = Time)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8, position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Area Use", fill = "Time") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("AvgAUPre" = "lightblue", "AvgAUPost" = "orange"),
    labels = c("AvgAUPre" = "Before", "AvgAUPost" = "After")
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]